# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, restful-url

Though am new to spring-mvc rest the concept looks clear in this code below. But I get the below mentioned exception which I have put after the code that is getting thrown :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/relationship")
public class RelationshipEndpoint  {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RelationshipEndpoint.class);

    @Autowired
    private IRelationshipService relationshipService;

    @PostMapping(name = ResourcePathConstants.RELATIONSHIP_LIST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> getListofRelationships(final HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
            @RequestBody @Valid RelationshipRequest request) {

        ServiceResponse result = true ? getResult(HrcaRelationshipListResponse.class, JsonConstants.RelationshipListResponse)
                : relationshipService.getListofRelationships(null);
        return prepareResponse(result);
    }

    @PostMapping(name = ResourcePathConstants.RELATIONSHIP_INFO)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> getRelationshipInfo(final HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
            @RequestBody @Valid RelationshipIdRequest request) {

        ServiceResponse result = relationshipService.getRelationshipInfo(request);
        return prepareResponse(result);
    }}
```

The exception below talk about ambiguity in resource which looks incorrect. kindly suggest.

```
 19-Apr-2018 12:49:47.585 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/HRCAWebApp]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'relationshipEndpoint' method 
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.company.core.io.model.web.response.ServiceResponse> com.company.api.endpoint.RelationshipEndpoint.getRelationshipInfo(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,com.company.core.io.model.web.request.RelationshipIdRequest)
to {[/relationship],methods=[POST]}: There is already 'relationshipEndpoint' bean method
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.company.core.io.model.web.response.ServiceResponse>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods for POST request. That is the problem. Try to add `path` attribute to remove the ambiguity.

```
    @PostMapping(name = ResourcePathConstants.RELATIONSHIP_LIST, path = {"/all"})
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> getListofRelationships(final HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
            @RequestBody @Valid RelationshipRequest request) {

        ServiceResponse result = true ? getResult(HrcaRelationshipListResponse.class, JsonConstants.RelationshipListResponse)
                : relationshipService.getListofRelationships(null);
        return prepareResponse(result);
    }

    @PostMapping(name = ResourcePathConstants.RELATIONSHIP_INFO, path = {"/info"})
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> getRelationshipInfo(final HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
            @RequestBody @Valid RelationshipIdRequest request) {

        ServiceResponse result = relationshipService.getRelationshipInfo(request);
        return prepareResponse(result);
    }
```

Because when you call `POST /relationship` Spring does not know which method to call (as you have 2).

And once you fix this you should call them like `/relationship/all` and `/relationship/info` or something like that.

Comment: Yes indeed I had to name it as `value` and not name. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have two POST actions for two identical URI:

```
/relationship
```

You have to change the POST actions by extend the URI by adding:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/some-uri", name = (...))
```

Comment: That's what I have done isn't it, they are 2 different URIs. I don't see where is the ambiguity.

Comment: When you don't write the property 'value' in the PostMapping on method, the actions point to the mapping from heading annotation. In your case getListofRelationships and getRelationshipInfo points to the same uri '/relationship' from the 'RequestMapping' heading annotation.

Comment: i think you have to change `@PostMapping(name = ResourcePathConstants.RELATIONSHIP_[...])`to `@PostMapping(value = ResourcePathConstants.RELATIONSHIP_[...])` and to ensure that your Path-Constants start with `/`